# Initialize video.js after page/content loaded via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, html5-video

I'm currently in the process of setting up [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) on one of my wordpress sites which loads the next set of posts via ajax once you've scrolled to the bottom of the page. Because of this, I have been unable to get videojs working properly (readas: at all); so am hoping someone can help me with this.

First and foremost, I'm using videojs code directly in my theme, which pulls data from a posts custom fields, and adds the post id to the video tags id attribute. Here's a sample of the template code:

```
<video id="video_<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
  poster="<?php echo $poster; ?>">  
 <source src="<?php echo $mp4vid; ?>" type='video/mp4' />  
</video>
```

(To note, I'll add ogg/webm later)

I've seen the docs page that says to add the following block:

```
_V_("example_video_1", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

but no matter where I add it (with the necessary attributes added), the player does not work. I mean, with the above I get standard html5 video player, but has none of the benefits of videojs.

Anyone have a working solution for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

referencing the correct ID might do the trick...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_V_("video_<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
</script>

<video id="video_<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
  poster="<?php echo $poster; ?>">  
 <source src="<?php echo $mp4vid; ?>" type='video/mp4' />  
</video>
```